# How to return string between brackets

Tags: python, string

The exercise is about distilling text. By scanning all the string in the text between two square brackets should be returned without the brackets. For example if the algorithm encounters [my] [name is] function should return my name is

This is my **code**:

```
text = """The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. 
Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. [Never gonna ] Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. 
[give you up\n] Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. 
Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox. [Never ] Bright vixens jump; [gonna let ] dozy fowl 
quack. Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim. Charged 
[you down\n] fop blew my junk TV quiz. How quickly daft jumping zebras vex. Two driven 
jocks help fax my big quiz. Quick, Baz, get my woven flax jodhpurs! "Now fax quiz Jack!" 
my brave ghost pled. [Never ] Five quacking zephyrs jolt my wax bed. [gonna ] Flummoxed 
by job, kvetching W. zaps Iraq. Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk. [run around ] 
A very bad quack might jinx zippy fowls. Few quips galvanized the mock jury box. Quick 
brown dogs jump over the lazy fox. The jay, pig, fox, zebra, and my wolves quack! 
[and desert you] Blowzy red vixens fight for a quick jump. Joaquin Phoenix was gazed 
by MTV for luck. A wizard’s job is to vex chumps quickly in fog. Watch "Jeopardy!", 
Alex Trebek's fun TV quiz game."""

def between_square(text):
    indx_sqr = ""
    indx_sqr2 = ""

    for num in range(len(text)):

        if text[num] in '[':
            indx_sqr += str(num) + '\n'
            print(num, 'this is the index of opening bracket')          
            print('encountered the opening square bracket')

        elif text[num] in ']':

            indx_sqr2 += str(num) + '\n'
            print(num, 'this is the indx of the closing bracket')
            print('encountered the closing square bracket')
         #   print(text[indx_sqr:indx_sqr2])
        else:
            continue
    return 'indices of all open brackets in the str:', indx_sqr, 'indicies of the closing one:', indx_sqr2


between_square(text)
```

**output:**

```
117 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
130 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
170 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
183 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
294 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
301 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
323 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
334 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
436 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
446 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
634 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
641 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
682 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
689 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
775 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
787 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
961 this is the index of opening bracket
encountered the opening square bracket
976 this is the indx of the closing bracket
encountered the closing square bracket
('indices of all open brackets in the str:',
 '117\n170\n294\n323\n436\n634\n682\n775\n961\n',
 'indicies of the closing one:',
 '130\n183\n301\n334\n446\n641\n689\n787\n976\n')
```

I would appreciate if somebody would give me idea how to continue this approach. idea was to get all the indices of square brackets and slice it. ([indx_sqr:indx_sqr2])

I'm aware that first I have to convert all the strings to integer, and probably loop all the 3digit indices in a way that it takes the whole 3digits not by character.

1. Is this is too much effort and complicated way to solve or it's doable?
2. I would really appreciate not using any advanced approaches for the sake of studying I want to understand all the methods such as(.split() , .strip()..etc) rather than using two lines of code.

Comment: Of course it's doable this way but usually one would use a list (or two) to store the indices as int numbers to avoid the conversion to/from string.

Comment: Actually, you are almost there, just save the indices of the opening and the closing brackets in lists and then you can slice and concetenate the strings. It's a bit hard to write an answer here, which doesn't spoil everything

Answer (score 3):

Expounding upon your idea, instead of storing the indices as `string` and then somehow converting them to `int`, I think it would be easier to store them as `int`s, and later converting them to `string`s, for printing:

```
def between_square(text):
    indx_sqr = []
    indx_sqr2 = []

    for num in range(len(text)):

        if text[num] in '[':
            indx_sqr.append(num)
            print(num, 'this is the index of opening bracket')          
            print('encountered the opening square bracket')

        elif text[num] in ']':

            indx_sqr2.append(num)
            print(num, 'this is the indx of the closing bracket')
            print('encountered the closing square bracket')
         #   print(text[indx_sqr:indx_sqr2])
        else:
            continue
    return 'indices of all open brackets in the str:', '\n'.join(map(str,indx_sqr)), 'indicies of the closing one:', '\n'.join(map(str,indx_sqr2))
```

This gives the exact same output.

[`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes an `iterable` as argument, containing `string`s, and joins with the `string` that it is called upon. Here `join` is called on `"\n"`, so each element will be joined with `"\n"`, but as the elements in the `iterable` (i.e. the `list`) are `integers`, we need to convert them to `string`. Here I use [`map(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), which maps the function passed in as first argument, is applied to every element of the `iterable` passed in the second argument.

Now, you can add this to the function:

```
for oi, ci in zip(indx_sqr, indx_sqr2):
    print(text[oi+1:ci])
```

Output:

```
Never gonna 
give you up

Never 
gonna let 
you down

Never 
gonna 
run around 
and desert you
```

Furthermore, using for loop with `for i in range(len(iterable)):` is not considered pythonic, for these kinds of tasks, python has [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which gives both the index and the value while iterating, so if we rewrite the code using `enumerate` it becomes more beautiful:

```
for num, char in enumerate(text):

        if  char == '[':
            indx_sqr.append(num)
            print(num, 'this is the index of opening bracket')          
            print('encountered the opening square bracket')

        elif char in ']':

            indx_sqr2.append(num)
            print(num, 'this is the indx of the closing bracket')
            print('encountered the closing square bracket')
        ...
```

Where `num` is the index, and `char` is the character that it is at the index `num`.

That said, this approach can be shortened considerably, without using very advanced techniques. I would give you a hint: initialize an empty list for the words in square brackets. Keep a flag variable, while iterating over the text, whenever you find a `'['` set `flag = True` and keep adding characters until you find `']'`, then set `flag = False`, add the string to your list, and set string to `''`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex: https://regex101.com/r/om4I2o/2

```
import re

text =  """The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. 
Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. [Never gonna ] Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. 
[give you up\n] Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. 
Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox. [Never ] Bright vixens jump; [gonna let ] dozy fowl 
quack. Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim. Charged 
[you down\n] fop blew my junk TV quiz. How quickly daft jumping zebras vex. Two driven 
jocks help fax my big quiz. Quick, Baz, get my woven flax jodhpurs! "Now fax quiz Jack!" 
my brave ghost pled. [Never ] Five quacking zephyrs jolt my wax bed. [gonna ] Flummoxed 
by job, kvetching W. zaps Iraq. Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk. [run around ] 
A very bad quack might jinx zippy fowls. Few quips galvanized the mock jury box. Quick 
brown dogs jump over the lazy fox. The jay, pig, fox, zebra, and my wolves quack! 
[and desert you] Blowzy red vixens fight for a quick jump. Joaquin Phoenix was gazed 
by MTV for luck. A wizard's job is to vex chumps quickly in fog. Watch "Jeopardy!", """

res = re.findall("\[(.*?)\n?\]", text)

print(res)
# ['Never gonna ', 'give you up', 'Never ', 'gonna let ', 'you down', 'Never ', 'gonna ', 'run around ', 'and desert you']
```

Comment: OP said, that he doesn't want to use advanced concepts, though